Persisting URI permissions using takePersistableUriPermission not working in Jetpack Compose
I'm tring to save a file to external storage and for that I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.
All works fine, my issue is that it asks for permission to access the selected folder every time the user picks a folder. I want the user to be able to select any folder they want each time, but if they've already granted my app permission to access a folder, I don't want them to be prompted for permission again.
My code:
val saveToDevicePickFolderLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) { uri ->
        uri?.let {
            try {
                App.instance.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(it, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                Logger.i { "Permissions persisted for URI: $it" }
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                Logger.e { "Failed to take persistable URI permission: ${e.localizedMessage}" }
            }
            viewModel.saveToDevice(selectedFileList, it, context)
            toggleSelectMode(on = false)
        }
    }

Then when debugging it I've tested out everything possible when launching the ActivityResultLauncher:
saveFileListToDevice = { list ->
   
    val persistedUriPermission = App.instance.contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions.firstOrNull()
    val persistedUri: Uri? = persistedUriPermission?.uri
    Logger.i { "Retrieved persisted URI $persistedUri with read? ${persistedUriPermission?.isReadPermission} and write? ${persistedUriPermission?.isWritePermission} permissions" }

    if (persistedUri != null) {
        try {
            // Ensure persistable URI permissions are granted for the persisted URI
            App.instance.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                persistedUri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            )
            Logger.i { "Permissions persisted for URI: $persistedUri" }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Logger.i { "Failed to take persistable URI permission: ${e.localizedMessage}" }
        }

        // Check if external storage is mounted and accessible
        when (val storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(File(persistedUri.path))) {
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED -> {
                Logger.i { "External storage is mounted and writable." }
            }
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY -> {
                Logger.i { "External storage is mounted, but read-only." }
            }
            Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED -> {
                Logger.i { "External storage is not available." }
            }
            else -> {
                Logger.i { "Unknown state for external storage: $storageState" }
            }
        }

        val documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, persistedUri)
        if (documentFile != null && documentFile.exists()) {
            // The URI is valid and the document exists
            Logger.i { "Document exists or URI is VALID" }
            saveToDevicePickFolderLauncher.launch(persistedUri)
        } else {
            Logger.i { "Document does not exist or URI is invalid" }
            saveToDevicePickFolderLauncher.launch(null)
        }
    } else {
        Logger.i { "Opening for input null" }
        saveToDevicePickFolderLauncher.launch(null)
    }
},

The logs I get are:
Permissions persisted for URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FA
Retrieved persisted URI UriPermission {uri=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FA, modeFlags=3, persistedTime=1732635607603} with read? true and write? true permissions
Permissions persisted for URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FA
Unknown state for external storage: unknown
Document exists or URI is VALID
Permissions persisted for URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FA

I've also tried persisting the URI to SharedPreferences but it makes no difference.
My checkpoints so far are:
1.Verified that takePersistableUriPermission() is called correctly both when selecting and accessing the folder. ✅
2.Checked persisted URIs using contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions to confirm both read and write permissions were granted. ✅
3.Checked if the URI is still valid using DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(). ✅
4.Checked the external storage state, but received state Unknown ❌ which might be the cause for this, I don't understand what can I do here?

"I can't manage to save the folder permission" -- your output suggests that this is working. "it gets re-requested everytime" -- you seem to call saveToDevicePickFolderLauncher.launch() in all cases. Hence, you will display that UI in all cases. Is that what you mean by "it gets re-requested everytime"?

I will update my question to clarify, my issue is that SAF asks for permission to access the selected folder every time the user picks a folder. I want the user to be able to select any folder they want each time, but if they've already granted my app permission to access a folder, I don't want them to be prompted for permission again.

I am not aware that developers have control over that behavior. That is especially true for Download/, which is the one you seem to be testing. Do you get different results if you create a custom folder (e.g., using the device's file manager, if it has one), then select that from your app?

I am using a custom folder, Downloads/A I know, very inspired... according to the docs we should https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

"I am using a custom folder" -- yes, but it is inside Download/, which Google wants to secure, because it is a dumping ground for lots of apps. I was suggesting that you try creating a new top-level folder, a peer of Download/, and see what you get when you use it.

just tried saving to a new peer folder now, same behavior :( but it was a good suggestion, thank you

OK, then I think you are out of luck. From Google's perspective, OpenDocumentTree() probably doesn't get used a lot -- apps request a folder, then use that folder for a long time. You might consider offering your own UI to switch between folders that have already been opened, with an option to open a new folder.
